# how to obfuscate assembled apk?

Tags: android, obfuscation

I have a bunch of apks which are already assembled and signed, but no source code. Now I want to obfuscate the them for experiment purpose. Is there any softwares or scripts I can count on? I know how to use proguard to obfuscate apk with source code. But it is not a workaround for my situation.

Comment: Do you want to `obfuscate` a piece of code once you create a package such as an `apk` so when some body else find your apk they will have a hard time to `diassemble` your package to find the code you wrote? Or do you want to `diassemble` an apk in order to find the files with the code written that has been packaged in it?

Comment: Actually, I want to obfuscate the apk content, say the classes.dex file to see what's the difference of entropy after obfuscation. And I didn't said I want to disassemble the apks to get the source code. I just mean what if I don't have the source code, how could I obfuscate them and produce the obfuscated apks.

Comment: Have you already tried this project: https://github.com/ClaudiuGeorgiu/Obfuscapk seems like is doing what you would like to achieve?

Comment: genius, thanks a million for your help. It really helped me.